# PHP > json_encode , force the creation of an array even if it has only one element

Tags: php, json

I take an xml from an external service via POST , and return the xml in json

this is an example of the xml

```
<xml>
     <item>
          <user>utente1</user>
          <psw>A722C63DB8EC8625AF6CF71CB8C2D939</psw>
          <code>A722C63DB8EC8625AF6CF71CB8C2D939</code>
     </item>
     <item>
          <user>utente2</user>
          <psw>A722C63DB8EC8625AF6CF71CB8C2D939</psw>
          <code>A722C63DB8EC8625AF6CF71CB8C2D939</code>
     </item>
</xml>
```

and with this procedure i transforms the xml in json

**php**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($getPostData);
$json = json_encode($xml);
```

**json result**

```
{
    "item": [
        {
            "user": "utente1",
            "psw": "A722C63DB8EC8625AF6CF71CB8C2D939",
            "code": "25BBDCD06C32D477F7FA1C3E4A91B032"
        },
        {
            "user": "utente2",
            "psw": "A722C63DB8EC8625AF6CF71CB8C2D939",
            "code": "25BBDCD06C32D477F7FA1C3E4A91B032"
        }
    ]
}
```

**and this is correct**. but there is a problem when the xml have only one item

```
 <xml>
      <item>
           <user>utente1</user>
           <psw>A722C63DB8EC8625AF6CF71CB8C2D939</psw>
           <code>A722C63DB8EC8625AF6CF71CB8C2D939</code>
      </item>
 </xml>
```

in this case the json is

```
{
    "item": {
        "user": "utente1",
        "psw": "A722C63DB8EC8625AF6CF71CB8C2D939",
        "code": "25BBDCD06C32D477F7FA1C3E4A91B032"
    }
}
```

item is an object in this case , and not an array with one element.

I wish it were so

```
{
    "item": [
        {
            "user": "utente1",
            "psw": "A722C63DB8EC8625AF6CF71CB8C2D939",
            "code": "25BBDCD06C32D477F7FA1C3E4A91B032"
        }
    ]
}
```

I read the documentation of [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/it/function.json-encode.php) and the [various json constants](http://php.net/manual/it/json.constants.php) , but i can't find an option to force this procedure. I proceed with a manual control or i can do it automatically? 
thank you

---

### UPDATE

My solution

```
//$getPostData = "<xml><item><user>utente1</user><psw>A722C63DB8EC8625AF6CF71CB8C2D939</psw><code>25BBDCD06C32D477F7FA1C3E4A91B032</code></item><item><user>utente1</user><psw>A722C63DB8EC8625AF6CF71CB8C2D939</psw><code>25BBDCD06C32D477F7FA1C3E4A91B032</code></item></xml>";   

$getPostData = "<xml><item><user>utente1</user><psw>A722C63DB8EC8625AF6CF71CB8C2D939</psw><code>25BBDCD06C32D477F7FA1C3E4A91B032</code></item></xml>";  

$xml = simplexml_load_string($getPostData);

$json = json_encode($xml);
$jsonCheck = json_decode($json);

$numItem =  sizeof($jsonCheck->item);

if($numItem == 1){
    $newJson = new stdClass();
    $newJson->item = array();
    $newJson->item[0]["user"] = $jsonCheck->item->user;
    $newJson->item[0]["psw"] = $jsonCheck->item->psw;
    $newJson->item[0]["code"] = $jsonCheck->item->code;
    $newJson = json_encode($newJson);
    echo $newJson;
}else{
    echo $json;
}
```

Comment: well, the function already does that, creating a manual checking is unavoidable.

Comment: yes a manual check is the only solution..

Comment: yes, quite straight forward, decode first, check if its just one, then create another nesting so that it would force another array inside. then encode again, if thats not the case, then just encode it.

Comment: yes exactly.I just wanted to know if there was an automatic solution , but the manual check is the only solution

Comment: `json_encode()` cannot help you with this. `SimpleXML` class is the one that exhibits this eccentric behaviour. Try to dump `$xml->item` and `$xml->item[0]` in the first example and you'll get the same thing while everybody expects that `$xml->item` will produce something that resembles an array. It is not an array but a `SimpleXMLElement` that implements the `Iterator` and probably the `ArrayAccess` interfaces.

Comment: What was your original goal (besides finding a way to get an array of `item`s when there is a single one in the XML)? Do you want to turn the XML into an array? Or an object/array mix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the structure of the entire XML and not just a fragment from something bigger, you can turn it into an array or a mix of arrays and objects using less code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($getPostData);

$array = array('item' => array());
foreach ($xml->item as $item) {
    $array['item'][] = (object)(array)$item;
}

echo(json_encode($array));
```

This will produce the output you described in the question as expected, no matter how many `<item>` elements appear in the XML.

Remove the `(object)` from the code inside the `foreach()` to get the `<item>` elements converted to arrays instead of `stdClass` objects.

Comment: @WhiteLine: would you consider accepting this answer?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, took me some time to figure out but I fixed it like this.

```
$somearray = array();

$_SESSION['activeChatBoxes'] = array_merge($somearray, $_SESSION['activeChatBoxes']);
```

If the session var activeChatBoxes only contains one item, it would be json_encoded as an Object. After merging into an empty array, the json_encode properly shows an array like

```
["string"]
```

Instead of:

```
{ 1, "string" }
```

Comment: Nice one, do you have any sources documenting this behavior?

Comment: @Gruber that is the source I copied. it is using a $_SESSION variable which is put into a json array. hope this clarifies it